# Vert.x HttpClientRequest setTimeout

Tags: timeout, httpclient, vertex

I'm using Vert.x 1.3.1-final and I'm trying to use the method setTimeout when sending a POST request from an HttpClient object, but I get an error: NosuchMethod.
The strange thing is that the method is defined and is public.

This is my code:

```
HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient()
            .setHost(config.getString(HOST))
            .setPort(config.getInteger(PORT))
            .setKeepAlive(true)
            .setConnectTimeout(config.getInteger(TIMEOUT));
HttpClientRequest clientRequest = client.post(endpoint, new ResponseHandler());
clientRequest.setTimeout(5*1000L);   // Exception: NoSuchMethod !!
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for your help.